# Some main-menu drop-down-items visibly faulty

Tags: menu-bar

[image]
[2](https://imgur.com/qpvIQTk.jpg): Screen-ruler image: https://imgur.com/qpvIQTk.jpg

Ubuntu v. 18.04 LTS  OS. Lately display weird, unusual partially greyed-out **main-menu** drop-down-items, concerning: „GParted“ and „Screen-ruler“ (Bildschirmlineal) applications.

At first all these drop-down-items were permanent visible.
For details see two attached display-photo / images. IMGUR: takes only one photo

How to solve this?  (Guessing: missing or broken third-party „theme-libs“)

Comment: No suggestions yet. - To understand this problem deeply the image: https://imgur.com/qpvIQTk might be helpfull.

Comment: What theme are you using? Have you tried to go back to the system's default theme? (Is it called Yaru on 18.04 too?) Do these problems show if you use the system's default theme?

Comment: Hallo Levente, thanks about your care. How do i find out what theme is used? How do i go back to the system default themes?

Comment: I am on 20.04, so I will have to guess what's it like on 18.04. I will guess you could use the _Settings_ app for that. It has an _Appearance_ item in the sidebar. It offers a choice between "Window colors", like Light, Standard, and Dark. This is the system-default theme, and its variants. (At least on 20.04.) So the normal _Settings_ app will let you choose only this theme. If you have additional themes installed, they were probably/possibly enabled with the _Gnome Tweaks_ app. With this app you can switch between all themes (including 3rd party themes) that are present on your system.

Comment: How do i find out by terminal command if Yaru or something else is in use? Sidebar Icon named: "KDE-Systemeinstellungen" and says Kubuntu is activ.

Comment: On 20.04 it's `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`

Comment: Oooohh KDE! I know nothing about KDE! :) Are you on Kubuntu? By all means put a `KDE` tag on your question. And also `kubuntu`, if that's your flavor. And also `theme`.

Comment: This is an other problem, some times ago my originally UBUNTU v. 18.04 OS installation start-screen changed into KUBUNTU from itself!. Terminal command says: "Ambiance"

Comment: Search for stories like "Ubuntu turned into PopOS" and "Ubuntu turned into Elementary OS". I think your story is pretty similar and will have a similar solution. This site had a few such threads in the past months; but try to search with external web search too, maybe it finds them easier. If you get stuck while de-KDE-ifying, post a new question specific to that.

Comment: Thanks so far as.-

Answer (score 0):

My request to the developer of the „Screen-Ruler“ Mr. Ian Mcintosh:
A fault concerning the context drop down menu comes up.
All items in this drop down menu are visibly only in grey.
Only when putting the cursor onto these items they become colored. The functions behind these items work well at all!

The developer answers 26.12.2020:
„I think screenruler has totally normal menus.  Are the menus weird in any other app, or just screenruler?“
My answer: The same phenomenon happens elsewhere.

Reply from Mr. Mcintosh: „Hmm it sounds like you have a problem with your "theme" and it might not be related to screenruler at all! :D“